# Is the return statement considered a jump instruction?

Tags: c++, return, goto

I'm not really advanced in C++, but I have a problem. My lecturer thinks `return` is a jump instruction like `goto`. I don't agree. In my opinion `return` is a control instruction that transfers control to the place where the function was called. If considered as a lecturer instructions such as `if`, `while`, `for` also jump instructions like `goto` because they bypass block of instructions.

My question is: What do you think about this? Is `return` a jump instruction?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're merely analyzing the problem at different levels, you're both right.  I'd argue that he's _slightly_ more right.  Also, this isn't a question.

Comment: @Daniel: I think with modern x86 it doesn't actually generate a `jmp` command, but a `ret` command, which is _very_ similar, but not identical.

Comment: Does this actually matter, *at all*, in any situation?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks, I took that out.

Comment: If you disassemble some sample compiled code with if/while/for etc., you will find lots of jumps.

Comment: @MooingDuck Are you sure about that? A `ret` command would *immediately* leave the current function, and not do any cleanups that may still be required, such as calling destructors for function-local objects.

Comment: Basically, this question depends on how you define "jump instruction", and there's no formal definition for that, so it's a matter of opinion (but you should probably use your lecturer's definition for the time being).

Comment: @hvd "there's no formal definition for that" - apparently that's incorrect, based on an answer just submitted.

Comment: @MarkRansom That answer is for "jump statement", not for "jump instruction". Either way, I'm considering it unlikely that either the OP or the lecturer are referring to the C++ standard. :)

Comment: @MarkRansom But is a jump statement a jump instruction? I didn't think the standard dealt with instructions.

Comment: What does this mean: "If considered as a lecturer instructions such as `if`, `while`, `for` also jump instructions..."?

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe the teacher won't allow the use of `return` because it is a `goto` in disguise? ;)

Answer (score 7):

In such disputable cases it is very useful to look through the C++ Standard and use definitions and terms that are used in the Standard.:)

According to the C++ Standard

> 6.6 Jump statements  1 Jump statements unconditionally transfer control.

```
jump-statement:
break ;
continue ;
return expressionopt;
return braced-init-list ;
goto identifier ;
```

Take into account that word instruction is used in the Standard to denote hardware instructions. They have nothing common with the C++ return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Written the following code in VS 2010:

```
int foo ()
{
   return 10;
}
```

Found the following in the disassembly:

```
  return 10;
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        eax 
00000004  cmp         dword ptr ds:[00413144h],0 
0000000b  je          00000012 
0000000d  call        65265BA7 
00000012  xor         edx,edx 
00000014  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],edx 
00000017  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0Ah 
}
0000001e  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
00000021  mov         esp,ebp 
00000023  pop         ebp 
00000024  ret
```

The last instruction is 'ret' equivalent to return.

Comment: add a `std::string a = "HI";` and see what happens to the assembly.  (I don't know, but it'd be interesting maybe.

Comment: True:) Why is he not able to give assembly when stepped line is std::string?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an important difference between a `return` and a `goto` statement (from a point of view of a higher-level language than assembly). As we know, a `goto` statement needs a `label` defined for jumping, and these labels have function scope. That means that in a code snippets like the following one:

```
int sample_fun()
{
   // code, possibly with local variables or gotos
 A:
   // code, possibly with local variables or gotos
 B:
   // code, possibly with local variables or gotos
}
```

labels `A` and `B` are visible from any point of the funcion `sample_fun`, even before the declaration of each label itself, and it doesn't introduces `scopes`, so labels are transparent for variables, and viceversa.

If in some point of that function there's a jump to another point of the same function, every "skipped" variable will be unitialized: for example, in `int a = 3;`, the identifier `a` will exist (it's visible) if it was declared in any previous place of the corresponding label, but its initializer (the value `3`) will be ignored (the corresponding initialization code won't be initialized). Even more, you could jump to a place inside a loop or inside an `if` statement, causing unstable states, difficulting compiler optimizations, and so on.

Although a `return` statement does also cause a "bypassing" of block instructions, its behaviour/state is "encapsulated", since a function have no access to local variables of previous scopes, and all of its behaviour depends only to its local variables (parameters included) --Ok, there exists globals, volatile variables and files.

Inside a function, you have only two possibilities: continuing its execution, or exiting the function as a whole, bringing every variable to death with him (executing the corresponding destructors callings and other clean ups), and a bypass of a trailing block of instructions inside a function will not cause any trouble: if you don't need them under some input preconditions, why should you execute them?.

No spaghetti code, no unstable states, not lack of understability.

In short, is a `return` statement a type of "jumping"?. Perhaps, it depends of your preferred definition of what you understand by "jumping", but the statements `goto`/`return` are definitively different and with different properties, according to the contexts they are used.